# If I never call "new," do I ever have to call "delete"?

Tags: c++, memory-management

If I manage to construct objects in C++ by doing

```
Object o;
```

instead of

```
Object *o = new Object();
```

in every case, do I ever need to call `delete` or will all memory be managed automatically?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. That object is allocated on the stack, and will be destroyed automatically when it goes out of scope. That includes freeing its memory and calling the destructor.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call `delete` on an object that was not allocated with `new`. Objects will be destroyed when they go out of scope.

Comment: Well, you *can*, but you *shouldn't*.

Comment: @Beta you can't do `delete o`. You can obviously do whatever you want with the address of `o`.

Comment: It's true that you can't `delete o`, but that has nothing to do with whether 'o' was allocated with `new`. And you should not `delete` an object that was not dynamically allocated, because that causes undefined behavior.

Comment: `delete` on stack-based objects simply do absolutely nothing.

Comment: @ViniyoShouta: Wrong. It's Undefined Behavior, and may set your computer on fire. Or send nasty emails to your boss. `delete` on `NULL`, on the other hand, is guaranteed to do nothing.

Comment: Yep. The last time I `delete`d a stack-based object, my dog got pregnant.